# The return type 'dynamic' isn't a 'Map<String, dynamic>?' from let

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the same func in different files, but here i got an error

```
    Map<String, dynamic>? getJson(String key) =>
      _sharedPreferences.getString(key)?.let((it) => jsonDecode(it));
```

```
 The return type 'dynamic' isn't a 'Map<String, dynamic>?', 
as required by the closure's context.dartreturn_of_invalid_type_from_closure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast it, see below

```
    Map<String, dynamic>? getJson(String key) =>
      _sharedPreferences.getString(key)?.let((it) => (jsonDecode(it) as Map<String, dynamic>));
```

Comment: oh thanks, i tried but it doesn't workkk now it's okay